# Running python script in Laravel Controller: "sh: 1: python: not found "

Tags: python, php, python-3.x, laravel, symfony

I am trying to run a python script in my Laravel PHP controller using Symfony Process. The python file is located in the public directory. The python file is:

```
import requests

URL = 'someURL.com'

response = request.get(url);

print(response)
```

Here is my code in my PHP Controller:

```
    $process = new Process('python '.public_path('MyPython.py'));

    $process->run();

    //executes after the command finishes
    if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
        throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
    }

    Log::error($process->getOutput());
```

When I run it I get this:

```
"message": "The command "python /var/www/project/public/MyPython.py" failed. Exit Code: 127(Command not found) Working directory: /var/www/project/public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ sh: 1: python: not found ",
```

While troubleshooting I created another python script called 'Simply.py' that just prints out "Hello World". When I run:

```
 $process = new Process('python '.public_path('Simply.py'));
```

The same error persists. But when I run:

```
 $process = new Process('python3 '.public_path('Simply.py'));
```

It is successful! I then try to run:

```
 $process = new Process('python3 '.public_path('MyPython.py'));
```

But then I get a new type of error, which is:

```
"message": "The command "python3 /var/www/project/public/MyPython.py" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: /var/www/project/public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/www/Matchban/public/MyPython.py", line 1, in <module> import requests ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' "
```

How can I either get it to run using the python command not python3, or how can I import the request module in my laravel project?

Comment: requests is not in standard library...so you need to install it

Comment: I have it installed on my local machine already

Comment: Also @Kurohige I can run the script on my local terminal via python MyPython.py and python3 MyPython.py just fine

Comment: then probably is a PATH problem. so need to set the whole path to the command

Comment: Could you explain a little more @Kurohige? Do I need to set the full path to the file?

Comment: Also, how would that correlate if I can run the simply.py fine?

Comment: If you're running this via the web interface it is running under a different user (and therefore with a different PATH variable) than when you run it in the console. If you do `sudo -iu www-data` (if you're using apache) you can check whether the same command works on the commandline

Comment: Hi there @apokryfos I will try that in a minute. As for right now I am doing it on a web interface but the project is currently hosted on my local machine